# React.js: Keyboard navigation

Tags: reactjs, navigation, redux

I am toying with an idea of rewriting our current Backbone-based app in React. One piece of functionality that is giving me headache is keyboard navigation. The app must be navigable using keyboard. Here is roughly what this looks like:

[image]

There is a header element with several buttons. There is also a main area with navigable elements that is built dynamically, from the results of a network request. The elements in the main area are arranged on the screen in a sort of grid (usually, 2 rows of 3 elements each, though on the mockup I showed rows of 2 elements).

The focus is initially on Element 1 (though if no elements have been fetched, then I guess a header button should be focused). Using arrow keys, one should be able to navigate within a component (from Element 1 to Element 2 with the right arrow key; from Element 2 to Element 1 with the left arrow key; from Element 1 to Element 3 with the down arrow key, and so on), and between components (from Element 1 to the header’s Button 1 with the up arrow ket; from header’s Button 1 to Element 1 with the down key, etc.). The elements that don't fit on the screen should be brought in view with the press of an arrow button when focused on an appropriate element (e.g., pressing right arrow when focused on Element 2 should "scroll" the main area to the right and bring Element 5 into the viewport).

Currently, in the original Backbone-based app, this functionality is achieved by adding a custom attribute to all navigable elements and then using a third-party jQuery-based library that calculates the absolute positions of the elements on the screen and moves the focus from one element to the next depending on how they are positioned relative to each other. What would be an idiomatic React (+ Redux, if possible) way to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: Not sure if this will add anything to the picture or just rehash the old solution you had, but I setup something a lot like that (also in a Backbone+jQuery app that I'm now doing in React). Basically doing what you described: looking at the siblings and comparing top or left coords based on left/right or up/down arrow. Much of the logic is in https://github.com/jmm/Jeopardy-Scorekeeper/blob/2eca1f1170a87e4ed9b56753b30ff26e3622ce7b/src/rsrc/view/dialog/dialog.js. With React, if you need to for some reason I guess you could use refs to children to find nodes in connection with component.

Comment: Hello @azangru Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ArtPip nope, sorry

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation:

Add and event listener to the container component for the elements. Set up an event listener in `componentDidMount` with a callback that somehow calculates what the next element is based on what button it was (hard for me to advise on this--if you are strict about only having 4 per page with max 2 rows, then you can do something like `(left) => current - 1`, `right (right) => current + 1`, `(down) => current + (count / 2)`, etc). That will fire an action like

```
{ type: ELEMENT_SELECTED, payload: { selectedElID } }
```

or if you're just keeping it in local state, `this.setState({ selectedEl })`

Then in your render function, always make sure that its rendering with the selected element in view.

Does that make sense?

Comment: It does make sense, thank you for the suggestion. The only problem with this approach that I see is that it assumes a lot (perhaps too much) about the structure of the page. What I would love to have is an approach that would be agnostic to the number of elements on the page and to their particular placement, but would rely only on the elements’ relative positions on the screen to guide the focus when moving from one element to the next.

Comment: By the way, how would you be listening to key press events?

Comment: Without doing any real vetting, this looks like it might be cool: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-keydown

That said, determining which one to go to next depends on your requirements. It might be useful to update your question with your requirements there, or as it as a different SO question. One idea that comes to mind is to sort through dom children and look for the ones that share common x positions on the page... I'll update my answer if I find time to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across with this old post today, but maybe a good solution for this kind of problem could be [React-Navetree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navtree) lib. It calculates distances between node to resolve who is the next/previous node, but it doesn't keep an active one.